# Implement regular tab with ion-tabs

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Is it possible to implement regular tabs with ion-tabs?

I mean like in a desktop app:

`Stuff above the tabs`

`Tabs 1` | `Tab 2` | `(white space covering the rest of the row)`
`Contents`

`Stuff below the tabs`

Comment: any reference design for this to understand your issue ?

Comment: @CodeChanger, thanks for asking. I can't show the design, but we need to implement tabs. However, ionic makes it impossible (or so I think) to implement the design which are classic tabs. Meaning that the tab buttons don't get stuck on top or bottom as a mobile or tablet app. Hope this clears it.

Comment: ok so as per my understanding you need your tab on top position not as per default bottom position in ionic m i right ?

Comment: @CodeChange, sorry but no. I need something like this: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/ Classic tabs right in the middle of the page.

Comment: ok so tab by default spread in whole screen but you need fix width tabs and it will not spread in whole screen with right ?

Comment: @CodeChanger, width is fine, it's more about the height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible but there is slight twist in naming in Ionic.

What you are looking for are called **segments** (which are basically tabs inside one page in contrary to "ionic tabs" which are separate pages). As per documentation:

> A Segment is a group of buttons, sometimes known as Segmented
>   Controls, that allow the user to interact with a compact group of a
>   number of controls. Segments provide functionality similar to tabs,
>   selecting one will unselect all others. You should use a tab bar
>   instead of a segmented control when you want to let the user move back
>   and forth between distinct pages in your app.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/segment/Segment/